What is difference between `aggregateGroupByDuration` and `aggregateGroupByPeriod` in Health Connect?
I am not able to understand the aggregation functions provided by Health Connect.
Here is the function to fetch activity records which uses aggregateGroupByDuration.
According to my understanding, based on the start and end date, it will fetch the data of the cumulative value of all the metrics that I have passed in the metrics parameter.
private suspend fun aggregateDataByBucketBasedOnDuration(
        healthConnectClient: HealthConnectClient,
        startTime: Instant,
        endTime: Instant
    ) {
        try {

            val response = healthConnectClient.aggregateGroupByDuration(
                AggregateGroupByDurationRequest(
                    metrics = setOf(
                        StepsRecord.COUNT_TOTAL,
                        DistanceRecord.DISTANCE_TOTAL,
                        TotalCaloriesBurnedRecord.ENERGY_TOTAL,
                    ),
                    timeRangeFilter = TimeRangeFilter.between(startTime, endTime),
                    timeRangeSlicer = Duration.ofDays(1)
                )

            )

            response.forEach { result: AggregationResultGroupedByDuration ->
                Timber.d(
                    "steps total: ${result.result[StepsRecord.COUNT_TOTAL]} " +
                            ",distance total: ${result.result[DistanceRecord.DISTANCE_TOTAL]} ," +
                            "calorie total: ${result.result[TotalCaloriesBurnedRecord.ENERGY_TOTAL]} ," +
                            "startTime:${result.startTime} ," +
                            "endTime: ${result.endTime}"
                )
            }


        } catch (e: Exception) {
            // Run error handling here
        }
    }


Here is the logs of this function when I ran it:
/** aggregateDataByBucketBasedOnDuration result: 
 * steps total: 6602 ,distance total: 3784.0138429299027 meters ,calorie total: 1714.9387687454107 kcal ,startTime:2024-08-16T18:30:00Z ,endTime: 2024-08-17T18:30:00Z
 * steps total: 2153 ,distance total: 946.9942807499685 meters ,calorie total: 1544.0814161167207 kcal ,startTime:2024-08-17T18:30:00Z ,endTime: 2024-08-18T18:30:00Z
 * steps total: 2181 ,distance total: 1217.345914414582 meters ,calorie total: 1534.8714048548898 kcal ,startTime:2024-08-18T18:30:00Z ,endTime: 2024-08-19T18:30:00Z
 * steps total: 1028 ,distance total: 414.3971366935903 meters ,calorie total: 1477.0066373640257 kcal ,startTime:2024-08-19T18:30:00Z ,endTime: 2024-08-20T18:30:00Z
 * steps total: 7444 ,distance total: 6496.074988999614 meters ,calorie total: 1941.2634706186748 kcal ,startTime:2024-08-20T18:30:00Z ,endTime: 2024-08-21T18:29:59.999Z
 */


I have verified the numbers mentioned in this. It is exactly what shown inside Health Connect app.
Now, I have created another function that fetches the same thing using the aggregateGroupByPeriod function instead of the aggregateGroupByDuration function.
private suspend fun aggregateDataByBucketBasedOnPeriod(
        healthConnectClient: HealthConnectClient,
        startTime: Instant,
        endTime: Instant
    ) {
        try {

            val response = healthConnectClient.aggregateGroupByPeriod(
                AggregateGroupByPeriodRequest(
                    metrics = setOf(
                        StepsRecord.COUNT_TOTAL,
                        DistanceRecord.DISTANCE_TOTAL,
                        TotalCaloriesBurnedRecord.ENERGY_TOTAL,
                    ),
                    timeRangeFilter = TimeRangeFilter.between(startTime, endTime),
                    timeRangeSlicer = Period.ofDays(1)
                )

            )

            response.forEach { result: AggregationResultGroupedByPeriod ->
                Timber.d(
                    "steps total: ${result.result[StepsRecord.COUNT_TOTAL]} " +
                            ",distance total: ${result.result[DistanceRecord.DISTANCE_TOTAL]} ," +
                            "calorie total: ${result.result[TotalCaloriesBurnedRecord.ENERGY_TOTAL]} ," +
                            "startTime: ${result.startTime} ," +
                            "endTime: ${result.endTime}"
                )
            }


        } catch (e: Exception) {
            // Run error handling here
        }
    }

I have getting this logs:
/** aggregateDataByBucketBasedOnPeriod
 * steps total: 3771 ,distance total: 2075.2305739754383 meters ,calorie total: 1613.5464919679039 kcal ,startTime: 2024-08-16T18:30 ,endTime: 2024-08-17T18:30
 * steps total: 6607 ,distance total: 3612.4783093918018 meters ,calorie total: 1715.328791728457 kcal ,startTime: 2024-08-17T18:30 ,endTime: 2024-08-18T18:30
 * steps total: 2150 ,distance total: 1203.0787563831184 meters ,calorie total: 1532.6618118549654 kcal ,startTime: 2024-08-18T18:30 ,endTime: 2024-08-19T18:30
 * steps total: 549 ,distance total: 234.74553567468138 meters ,calorie total: 1474.9617246142407 kcal ,startTime: 2024-08-19T18:30 ,endTime: 2024-08-20T18:30
 * steps total: 7916 ,distance total: 6671.767744403136 meters ,calorie total: 1945.517986367616 kcal ,startTime: 2024-08-20T18:30 ,endTime: 2024-08-21T18:29:59.999
 */

I am trying to understand how these numbers are calculated. In both functions, I used 1 day for timeRangeSlicer. So, how come this number is different from the above logs?
Please enlighten me.
I also went through the docs to understand this.
But not able to understand how this function work beside the scene which produce different number.
